# Shopware 6 theme isnt overriding Storefront?

Tags: html, plugins, twig, shopware, commerce

I am trying to override the storefront using my plugin files and doesnt seem to be working. I am using Shopware 6.

I am trying to follow the example they give to set it up, overriding the logo.html.twig in the header.

My file directory is:

```
Installation root > custom > plugins > MY PLUGIN NAME > src > Resources > views > shopfront > layout > header > logo.html.twig
```

Inside my logo file I have :

```
{% sw_extends '@Storefront/storefront/layout/header/logo.html.twig' %}

{% block layout_header_logo_link %}
    <h2>Hello world!</h2>
{% endblock %}
```

I have ran `bin/console cache:clear` as well as `./psh.phar cache` and `bin/console theme:compile`.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try changing your path to `views/storefront/layout/header/logo.html.twig` according to the original path and the documentation?

Comment: @jord49 Did you solve the issue?

Comment: In my case, it works after I run `./psh.phar cache`

Answer (score 1):

Your directory should be src/Resources/views/storefront/layout not shopfront.

After fixing the directory, reinstall the plugin and clean the cache. by bin/console cache:warmup and bin/console http:cache:warm:up

Answer (score 0):

Turned out I had pulled the master install branch and not the latest release.